# how to get group by field and ther auto ids in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table in that I have 2 fields: `Logid` and `Type`:

```
 +---------+---------+
 |  Logid  |  Type   |
 +---------+---------+
 |    1    |  PHP    |
 |    2    |  Mysql  |
 |    3    |  PHP    |
 |    4    |  JAVA   | 
 |    5    |  PHP    | 
 |    6    |  MYSQL  |
 +---------+---------+
```

I need to get all `Logid`  by `logs_operationtype` group,
I need to get the output as:

```
 +------------+---------+
 |  Logid     |  Type   |
 +------------+---------+
 |    1,3,5   |  PHP    |
 |    2,6     |  Mysql  |
 |    4       |  JAVA   |
 +------------+---------+
```

Comment: When you say "*I need to get the output as...*", are you **sure** that's what you **need**?  It's generally better to *sort* your table e.g. with `SELECT Logid, Type FROM myTable ORDER BY Type` and then keep track of the last seen `Type` (to detect changes) when looping over the resultset.  Perhaps an instance of [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) .

Comment: eggyal's solution is the correct one.  Please don't use `GROUP_CONCAT` for something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/04/group_concat-useful-group-by-extension/)

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Logid) AS Logid, Type 
FROM  <tablename> 
GROUP BY Type
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
   group_concat(Login) as LogId,
   Type
FROM
   myTable
GROUP BY Type
```